# Check if all the 5 digits in a given 5 digit number are same

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show an alert if all the 5 digits in a given 5 digit number are same for example 11111, 22222, etc. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/09k8f5s4/36/ and below is my code which is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
      <input type="text" ng-model="value"/>
     <button ng-click=check()>Check</button>
 </div>

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('test', function($scope) {
      $scope.check = function() {
          if(/(\d)\1{2}-\1{3}-\1{4}/.test($scope.value)) {
            alert("Invalid number");      
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: are you sure your regex is correct?

Comment: Check out ng-pattern instead. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Comment: @VtoCorleone no its not correct. I just tried that.

Comment: @Matthew is there a way to do it with regex like the way i tried to do.

Comment: Yes. ng-pattern takes a regex and updates the invalid flag for the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex  `^([0-9])\1*$`

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('test', function($scope) {
      $scope.check = function() {
          if(/^([0-9])\1*$/.test($scope.value)) {
            alert("Invalid number");      
          }
      }
});
```

see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/09k8f5s4/43/)

Answer (score 2):

You imply you know there are exactly 5 integers present, so I would test against mod11111.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick vanilla version (I'm not really familiar with Angular):

```js
var num = 44444;
var num2 = 44445;

function areSame(num) {
    var arr = String(num).split('');
    return arr.every(function (el) { return el === arr[0]; });
}

console.log(areSame(num));
console.log(areSame(num2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain JavaScript.  Assuming `number` is a string:

```
function isAllSameDigit(number){
    for(var i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
        if(number[0] != number[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will short circuit as soon as a difference is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(input) {
  // convert input to string 
  input += "";

  // verify only 5 characters
  if (input.length !== 5) {
    throw new Error("Input is not 5 digits long.");
  }

  // verify it is numeric.
  if (!$.isNumeric(input)) {
    throw new Error("Input is not a numeric value.");
  }

  var allSame = true;
  var firstChar = input[0];

  // Loop through looking for something different
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (input[i] !== firstChar) {
      allSame = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  return allSame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey your regx is not correct :-

Use:- /^\D*(\d)(?:\D*|\1)*$/.test($scope.value)

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('test', function($scope) {
      $scope.check = function() {
          if(/^\D*(\d)(?:\D*|\1)*$/.test($scope.value)) {
            alert("Invalid number");      
          }
      }
});
```

Fiddle :-http://jsfiddle.net/95ydag0b/